# Finish activity from activity group

Tags: android, activitygroup

I have a problem look like this. I have 5 activity group and 1 tabHost with 5 tab and every tab is attached with one activity group. In each activity group a Login activity.

Condition:

1. When we tap with in 1,2,3,4 and 5 tab the Login activity is show.//according to requirement.
2. After login another activity is start and these activity add in activitygroup.

Problem:

When we press back button after login the the login form is show I want to remove it after login. I have use all the finishing method provided by Android sdk like finish(), finishFormChield() and others also.

Answer (score 0):

In the login activity when you start intent, immediately include finish(). This kills the present activity as shown below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(first.java,second.class);
startActivty(intent);
finish();
```

You can also try with including android:launchMode="singleInstance" in your android manifest file for the activty as shown below:

[single instance activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Comment: Thank for giving answer.. I have already try finish() after staring the activity but the hole activityGroup is finish.